# mod_rewrite increases load time

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am using `mod_rewrite` on my site url right now. Almost done. Before doing this my site was fast. Now it takes 2 or 3 seconds to load and a blank white loading page appears first.

Is it usual for page loading to take more time when using mod_rewrite?

Link without Mod Rewrite http://www.wapinside.com/Songs/webindex.php

Link with Mod Rewrite http://www.wapinside.com/Songs/webindex2.php

This is what is in my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^w/([^*]+).html$ webindex2.php?dir=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^web/([0-9]+)/([^*]+).html$ webindex2.php?page=$1&dir=$2 [L]
```

`w/` is for folders and `web/` is for folder pages.

Comment: I didn't notice any lag between the two...Possibly you are on a slow connection and `http://www.wapinside.com/Songs/webindex.php` is cached?

Comment: Both links loaded at the same speed (visually) to me. This included a force reload test.

Answer (score 1):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

"Using a high trace log level for mod_rewrite will slow down your Apache HTTP Server dramatically!"

You might be using it. From the documentation, that seems like the only way mod_rewrite could slow down Apache.